# aspx page click on mailto href and other buttons don't fire

Tags: asp.net, href, aspbutton

I have an aspx page(running .net 4 framwork **not MVC**) that has an mailto that is using an href and also has a .  The link button works correctly firing off code behind.  If i click on the href with the mailto (it will fire up outlook with the correct info) and after that try to click on the link button, the  does not fire.  The  looks like this when rendered.

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSave" value="Save Attendance" onclick="return checkDisableButton(this.id, 'PROCESSING');" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSave" class="ButtonPrimary button" disabled="">
```

The checkDisabledButton code

```
function checkDisableButton(btn, parmText, icon) {
var mbtn = $('#' + btn);
mbtn.addClass("buttonPad buttonProcessing button");
mbtn.val(parmText);};
```

i put a breakpoint at the var mbtn line and it doesn't hit it after the mailto link is clicked on.  It does fire if i load the page and don't click on the mailto link.

Just so you have it.. the href looks like this

```
<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_hlMailto" href="mailto:a@a.com;%20b@b.com;%20?Subject=2846">Load email</a>
```

(I edited out some info on that href so i may have messed it up on the copy)

I inspected the code of the  before and after the mailto is clicked and it does not appear to have changed.

Anyway.. was wondering if anyone had any ideas...
thanks
shannon

Comment: once I had problems with that, but the problems happened only on Google Chrome. I don't know if that is your case. Have you tried other browsers just in case?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried in both IE and Chrome.. it acts the same in both..

Answer (score 0):

not saying it's the perfect way.. but figured out something.  i had some more code that i didn't think to include that disabled the button after it was clicked so that it wouldn't run more than once.  This was the code that was having the issue with the mailto.  That code looked like this

```
function DisableButtons() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i in inputs) {
    if (inputs[i].type == "button" || inputs[i].type == "submit") {
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

}
window.onbeforeunload = DisableButtons;

i commented out that code and added this code to the checkDisableButton function

```
 $(mbtn).one('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //do something 
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);

        })
```

this makes it so that the button can only be clicked one time.  it seems to be working.
thanks
shannon